Symfony 7 : flash message not showing
I’m writing here because someone may have already solved this problem:
Here’s my code:
$form = $forumService->handleDiscussionForm($request);

if ($form === "submitted") {
    $this->addFlash('success', 'Your discussion has been successfully created and must be validated by Parentela.');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_forum_thematique', ['slug' => $thematique->getSlug()]);
}

Test 1:
When I submit my form with this code, I am correctly redirected to the "app_forum_thematique" route, but the flash message does not display.
Test 2:
$form = $forumService->handleDiscussionForm($request);

if ($form === "submitted") {
    $this->addFlash('success', 'Your discussion has been successfully created and must be validated by Parentela.');
    dd("test");
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_forum_thematique', ['slug' => $thematique->getSlug()]);
}

If I add a dd("test") and submit my form, the "test" displays.
I then remove it from the code and refresh my page.
At that point, the flash message displays, and I am correctly redirected.
Question is : why doesn’t this work without the manipulation with the dd("test")?
Have you ever encountered this problem?
Thanks for your help :)

If I understand correctly, you want to display the message on the current page - before being redirected? As far as I know, this is not how the flash messages work. They're made to be displayed on the 'next page'. They're set to the session, and are shown after the redirect. To display a message on the current page you could use Symfony UX, Stimulus or just plain JS (amongst others).

Do you have a for loop  in your template to render the flash messages ? And you can add the flash message before the redirection it's not an issue because it's stored in the session

@JulianKoster Hello, thank you for your help. No, what I want is the usual behavior: flash message -> redirection -> display on the new page.

@MoWiz : Hey, hello, yes, I do have the loop, otherwise I wouldn't be able to display the message when I use dd("test") and then refresh the page.
My problem is that without a dd("message") stopping the program and then manually refreshing, my flash message is not displayed, as if it wasn’t stored in the session, even though this code is being executed.. :(

@Alan you are right i missed the part of the question when you said usin the dd helped display the flash :). Very akward behaviour indeed. Have you tried to dump the session on your redirection page to check if there is not a part of your application that reset/delete the session ? Because if the message is stored in the session it gotta be displayed

I got it.
And that's strange, but maybe someone can explain it ?
My probleme was because of turbo : When i add data-turbo="false" on my button, my flash message reappear.
So it seems that without "data-turbo=false", turbo preload my "submit click", load the flash message and don't reload it when i do the real click, which is not really usefull :x
